# Understanding the solution of a second order differential equation by combination of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading the paper [*The dielectric lamellar diffraction grating*](https://mcgrating.com/references/ref05.pdf), in which the following ODE is solved for $u$: $$u^{''}+\zeta^{2}S(x-c)u=-\beta^{2}u,$$ where
$\zeta^{2}=k_2^2-k_1^2$, $\beta^2=k_1^2-\mu^2$, $S(x)=0$ for $x < 0$ and $S(x)=1$ for $x\geq0$.

They do this the following way, which I don't understand at all:

Let $\theta$ and $\psi$ be two linearly independent solutions which are continuous and continuously differentiable at $x = c$, such that $\theta(0) = 1$, $\psi(0) = 0$, $\theta^{'}(0) = 0$, $\psi^{'}(0) = 1$.

Then for $0\leq x\leq c$, we have that $$\theta = \text{cos}(\beta x),\;\;\;\psi=\frac{1}{\beta}\text{sin}(\beta x)$$ and for $c<x$ we have that $$\theta=\text{cos}(\beta c)\text{cos}(\gamma(x-c))-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\text{sin}(\beta c)\text{sin}(\gamma(x-c)),$$ $$\psi=\frac{1}{\beta}\text{sin}(\beta c)\text{cos}(\gamma(x-c))+\frac{1}{\gamma}\text{cos}(\beta c)\text{sin}(\gamma(x-c)),$$

where $\gamma^{2}=\beta^{2}+\zeta^{2}$.

Can somebody please explain to me what is going on here? Why these two solutions? Where do all the sin/cos come from?

## EDIT

(based on answers)

The ODE is a piecewise defined function, so let's look at it piece by piece.

### $x < c$

in this case: $x-c< 0$, hence $S(x-c) = 0$, and the ODE becomes:

$$u^{''}=-\beta^{2}u,$$

for which [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27%28x%29%3D-b%5E2*u%28x%29) is:

$$u(x) = c_1 \cos(\beta x) + c_2 \sin(\beta x) $$

### $x \geq c$

in this case: $x-c \geq 0$, hence $S(x-c) = 1$, and the ODE becomes:

$$u^{''}+\zeta^{2}u=-\beta^{2}u$$
which can be rewritten as:
$$u^{''}=-(\beta^{2}+\zeta^{2})u$$
substituting $m^2 = \beta^{2}+\zeta^{2}$
we obtain again the same kind of equation as for the first piece ($x < c$) of the function:

$$u^{''}=-m^2u$$

for which [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27%28x%29%3D-b%5E2*u%28x%29) is:

$$u(x) = c_1 \cos(m x) + c_2 \sin(m x) $$

resubstituting:

$$u(x) = c_1 \cos(\sqrt{\beta^{2}+\zeta^{2}}x) + c_2 \sin(\sqrt{\beta^{2}+\zeta^{2}} x) $$

So, I still don't understand:

1. The use of $\theta$ and $\psi$ ?
2. Their solution compared to the one posted here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please [choose a better title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144). The current one has no mathematical content.

Comment: Little latex hints `<=` should be `\le` (less or equal) and `cos` should be `\cos`...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for those hints. I didn't know about it. Very useful. Also, would you mind to have a look at my edited question?

Comment: It's very clean like this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, before $x=c$, this equation is just $u’’=-\beta^2 u.$ This is one of the most basic equations studied in an ODE course, and its solutions are linear combinations of $\sin \beta x$ and $\cos \beta x.$ After $x=c,$ you have the same form of equation, with $\gamma^2$ taking the place of $\beta^2.$ The complicated coefficients make the solutions continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Would you mind having a look at my edited question? Thanks to your answer I have been able to explore the derivation a bit further, but I am still stuck on a few things. I would highly appreciate your help.